# Error when viewing list of taxonomy terms

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, updating

I'm getting an "unexpected error" when I try to view a list of taxonomy terms. I recently updated to 8.7, though I have a feeling the problem has been around since before the update. Here's the error as it appears in watchdog:

> Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AS expression FROM tfr INNER JOIN tr ON tfr. = tr. AND tr. = 0 INNER JOIN (S' at line 1: SELECT tfr.tid AS tid, MAX(tfr.) AS expression FROM {} tfr INNER JOIN {} tr ON tfr. = tr. AND tr. = 0 INNER JOIN (SELECT t.tid AS tid, t.langcode AS langcode, MAX(t.) AS expression FROM {} t WHERE t. = :db_condition_placeholder_0 GROUP BY t.tid, t.langcode) mr ON tfr. = mr. AND tfr.langcode = mr.langcode GROUP BY tfr.tid; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 1 ) in Drupal\taxonomy\TermStorage->getTermIdsWithPendingRevisions() (line 404 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/libnews/core/modules/taxonomy/src/TermStorage.php).

And I don't know if this related, but I am also getting an error when I try to update my database via drush:

> Error: Call to a member function getKey() on null in system_update_8702() (line 2278 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/libnews/core/modules/system/system.install) #0

This is outside my area of expertise, so I'm pretty stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a similar error on my server too. 
I had to change the function in TermStorage.php to get it to work.

Just a warning, this core hack and should be reverted once it is fixed in core. 
Replace getTermIdsWithPendingRevisions() with the following:

```
  public function getTermIdsWithPendingRevisions() {
$table_mapping = $this->getTableMapping();
$id_field = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($this->entityType->getKey('id'))['value'];
$revision_field = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($this->entityType->getKey('revision'))['value'];
$rta_field = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($this->entityType->getKey('revision_translation_affected'))['value'];
$langcode_field = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($this->entityType->getKey('langcode'))['value'];
$revision_default_field = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($this->entityType->getRevisionMetadataKey('revision_default'))['value'];

$query = $this->database->select($this->getRevisionDataTable(), 'tfr');
$query->fields('tfr', [$id_field]);
$query->addExpression("MAX(tfr.$revision_field)", $revision_field);

$query->join($this->getRevisionTable(), 'tr', "tfr.$revision_field = tr.$revision_field AND tr.$revision_default_field = 0");

$inner_select = $this->database->select($this->getRevisionDataTable(), 't');
$inner_select->condition("t.$rta_field", '1');
$inner_select->fields('t', [$id_field, $langcode_field]);
$inner_select->addExpression("MAX(t.$revision_field)", $revision_field);
$inner_select
  ->groupBy("t.$id_field")
  ->groupBy("t.$langcode_field");

$query->join($inner_select, 'mr', "tfr.$revision_field = mr.$revision_field AND tfr.$langcode_field = mr.$langcode_field");

$query->groupBy("tfr.$id_field");
return 0;
//return $query->execute()->fetchAllKeyed(1, 0);
```

}

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm. In your case, do you know what caused the initial problem?

Comment: This happens when the entity type definition (stored in key_value table) is malformed.

Comment: If you're going to patch this function I would suggest returning an empty array at the beginning, rather than returning 0 at the end.  This would probably cause problems with content moderation, so check that functionality if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I have Drupal core version 8.7.2 and `drush updb -y` fixed the error:

> taxonomy module :   Update taxonomy terms to be revisionable.   Remove
>   the 'hierarchy' property from vocabularies.